# Convert a String to a Decimal

Tags: apex, decimal

in my code I need to put a String contained inside a map in a Decimal variable. Now I have 2 problems, the first one is the format of the String because it can contain **' , '** and **' . '** e.g. '21,31' or '3.124,23', the second one is that when I use Decimal.ValueOF(string) method System gives me "invalid decimal error" despite my code.
Here my code:

```
[...]
if(fieldMapped.contains('UnitPrice')){   
System.debug(mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t].right(4));
//controll over price format
if(mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t]!=''){    
   if((mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t].right(4)).contains('.')){               
      mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t]=mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t].remove(',');
   }else if((mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t].right(4)).contains(',')){
      mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t]=mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t].remove('.').replace(',','.');                     
   }else{
      mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t]='0';
   }
   oli.UnitPrice = Decimal.ValueOf(mapFieldColumn.get('UnitPrice')[t]);
   }
}       
[...]
```

The system debug shows the error:
"Exception: System.TypeException: Invalid decimal:  € 28836.81 ".
The String I was trying to cast is = "2.8836,81"

Comment: I've removed "cast" from your question as you are using the correct approach of a factory method rather than a cast that would be `((Decimal) stingVariable)`.

Comment: thank you keith, convert is absolutely more appropriate.

Comment: I understand what it's the problem. The String can contain also special char like: € or $ that indicate the current currency. Now I'm working on a way to eliminate this type of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a regular expression and the [replaceAll()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method.

The following expression will identify any character that is not a decimal point or a digit. You can try it out at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

```
[^.\d]
```

In Apex you'll need to escape the slash...

```
[^.\\d]
```

By this you'll be able to strip out the comma without having to go searching for it.

```
String value = '12,345.678';
system.assertEquals('12345.678', value.replaceAll('[^.\\d]','');
system.assertEquals(12345.678, Decimal.valueOf(value.replaceAll('[^.\\d]',''));
```

This cleaned-up value should convert to a Decimal without giving an error. You may also find it helpful to create a utility method that takes the String to be converted as well as a Decimal value to return if an error occurs.

Comment: I take this opportunity to ask you, there is a regex espression that allow me to replace all the currency's simbols. For Example in my org someone use $ someone use €. The same user can use both Dollar or Euro depends on the opportunity

Comment: The same code provided above will also strip out any currency symbols from a string value, these being neither numeric nor a decimal point. So you could use the same code, then apply some other logic to determine which is the correct symbol to be displayed. If you're working in a multi-currency environment or have a need to convert between USD and EUR, then asking that in a separate question is a better approach then replacing currency symbols.